# Spring MVC how to forbid data binding to ModelAttribute?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a simple `@Controller` class that renders a page after user has logged in:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class DashBoardController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/user/dashBoard", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showDashBoardPage(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
        //do some work here....
        return "dashBoard";
    }

}
```

as you see, `user` attribute is already present in session and by using `@ModelAttribute` annotation I only want to pull it from there, nothing else. But if you add any parameter to request, then spring tries to bind this parameter to existing user object, which is not what I want, how to forbid this behavior?

To be more specific, here's the User class:

```
public class User {

   private String name;
   private String password;
   private Language language;

   //public getters and setters here...
}
```

If I want to change language of my `dashBoard` page, I request this page with addition of `?language=en` parameter and in this case Spring tries to change language field of user model attribute, which of course fails with type mismatch exception.
Of course I can walk around by changing parameter name to something that doesn't match any of `User` fields, but that seems like a fragile solution. 
Is there any way to control this data binding behavior?
I use Spring 4.1.3

Comment: Don't use `@ModelAttribute` for that... If it isn't used for data binding don't use it... If you want to have the logged in user you should integration with the normal security stuff and use a `Principal` if you really want to use your custom solution create your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which knows what to do with a `User`.

Comment: You should be able to get `user` through `model`, which obviates the need for `@ModelAttribute("user") User user` altogether.

Comment: Thank you for comments, for now I decided to use ModelMap#get() to pull the user from session, but later I will move to Spring security as it's intended to handle this functionality.

Answer (score 10):

There is an attribute of `@ModelAttribute` called `binding` which you can set to false to disable binding of request parameters. Usage: `@ModelAttribute(binding=false)` before method parameter.

Reference: [click](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args)